# dask - AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, dask

I have over 8 million rows of text where I want to remove all stop words and also lemmatize the text using dask.map_partitions() but get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'`

Is there any way to apply the function to the dataset?

Thanks for the help.

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from spacy.lang.en import stop_words

cachedStopWords = list(stop_words.STOP_WORDS)

def stopwords_lemmatizing(text):
    return [word for word in text.split() if word not in cachedStopWords]

text = 'any length of text'
data = [{'content': text}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)

ddf['content'] = ddf['content'].map_partitions(stopwords_lemmatizing, meta='f8')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map_partitions`, as the name suggests, works on each partition of your overall dask dataframe, which are each pandas dataframes ( http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html#design ). Your function value-by-value for a seriesq, so what you actually wanted was the simple `map`:

```
ddf['content'] = ddf['content'].map(stopwords_lemmatizing)
```

(if you want to provide the meta here, it should be a zero-length Series rather than dataframe, e.g., `meta=pd.Series(dtype='O')`).